# WordPress theme editor is missing

Tags: wordpress, themes, admin

I am trying to access the theme editor in WordPress.

The problem is that I cannot find the option under Admin-Appearances -  Editor and when I try to access the page using the link http://www.nameofsite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php I get the error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I am logged in as an administrator. Why can't I find the editor option?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is probably because of iThemes Security and its settings. So yeah, just go to wp-config and change DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT to false.

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );
```

Or just switch it off here:
*Dashboard -> Security -> WordPress Tweaks -> Configure Settings*

Uncheck: Disable File Editor

Comment: I can't find 'Security' within 'Dashboard'

Comment: In Ithemes Security setting -> settings -> advanced ->  Wordpress Tweaks then uncheck: Disable File Editor

Answer (score 17):

Open up your *wp-config.php* file, and search for

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

Change true to false:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using Siteground hosting `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);` won't work. Sitegound hosting provide SG Security plugin by default on direct WordPress installation from cPanel and it blocks the `Theme Editor` and `Plugin Editor` option by default.

To enable the Theme Editor and Plugin Editor option you just need to disable the option called `Disable Themes & Plugins Editor` under Site Security. Here is the path to disable that option :

> Click on **SG Security** -> **Site Security** -> **Disable
> Themes & Plugins Editor Option**

That's it. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: saved my day...

Comment: Mine also, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

## Hack:

Manually browse: *domain.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php*

Comment: This won't work. The following issue will occur.
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Comment: Worked for me on wordpress.com.

Comment: @BeaST30 may be you are not admin of that site.

Answer (score 5):

If you used **Siteground** host.. you can enable theme editor that option:

1. Go to domain.com/wp-admin.php
2. SG Security
3. Site Security
4. Disable Themes & Plugins Editor Option

I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

At root directory of your wordpress. Open up your wp-config.php file, and search for

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

Change true to false:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sucuri WordPress plugin will also disable the editor in its settings under the "Hardening" tab. You can click on *Revert Hardening*, make your changes, and then go back and apply hardening when you're finished.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that it is being blocked by a security plugin or the like. In my case SG security (from siteground) had an option active that deactivated the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove both codes

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

After this just refresh, the dashboard Theme editor will appear.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the theme editor, follow these steps:

1. Go to *Appearance*, select one theme (any one you like) and activate it.
2. In this activated theme, go to *Appearance* → *Editor* → select the theme to edit (on the top right, above *Templates*. There is a drop-down click on it and select your previous theme.)
3. Now select *config.php* or *demo config.php* and remove the define ( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT, true); code.
4. Now click on *Update file*.
5. Now change the theme to your previous theme.

Now you can find your editor in the *Appearance* drop-down.

Comment: thank you but i could find appearance in the options of porto themes for wordpress.

Comment: This isn't correct, the questioner's issue is that appearance --> editor isn't appearing, you're telling them to use that path within the answer. The problem is a security setting as talked about below, they need to go into wp-config.php or deactivate this security feature with the plugin they are using.

Answer (score 0):

There might have set `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT` constant value to `true` somewhere in your wordpress website.
All you need to do is set that value to `false`.

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```

It should be in `wp-config.php` or `wp-settings.php` usually. But it could be in some where else depends on the website builder.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you are using a block enabled theme, it's no longer possible to edit your theme and plugin files directly from within WordPress. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/link-to-plugin-editor-missing-when-using-twenty-twenty-two-theme/